# Protobuf: enum with default value

Tags: enums, protocol-buffers

In google's Protocol Buffers, I use large enums and I have to assign each integer value explicitly:

```
  enum Function {ProcessLibrary=0;
                 RotateLeft=1;
                 RotateRight=2;
                 ...}
```

This is very annoying and ugly. Is there a way to avoid these integer values in the code?
something like:

```
  enum Function {ProcessLibrary;
                 RotateLeft;
                 RotateRight;
                 ...}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, basically. This is deliberate to prevent huge errors when adding / removing enums, and to allow for non-contiguous enums.

In most real-world cases where the list of names is already defined elsewhere, you can write a 5 line script to add `=n` onto each - heck, a spreadsheet calculation and "fill down" would go a long way to it - paste names into the first column, copy the generated lines out of the second.

Comment: I agree, but I have both client and server in the same build, so I will not have such errors. It is strange that protobuf doesn't give this option (that is not problematic at all for some applications such as mine)

Comment: @zvisofer the point of robust serialisation is not just that it works for 2 nodes built at the same time. It is that it works correctly for data saved on disk, or in flight, or between different versions. Frankly there's no compelling reason to omit it.

Comment: @zvisofer Protobuf doesn't give you the option because too many people who _do_ require forwards- and backwards-compatibility would then omit the numbers and end up shooting themselves in the foot, whereas requiring them is not a huge burden for those who don't need them.